# how to remove all spaces from a file

Tags: css, whitespace, space

I recently downloaded a css file and I accidentally formatted it to this:

```
.clearfix{*zoom:1}.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{display:table;content:"";line-

height:0}.clearfix:after{clear:both}.hide-text{font:0/0 a;color:transparent;text-

shadow:none;background-color:transparent;border:0}
```

for about 10,000 lines.

How can I remove all the spaces so it looks like:

```
.clearfix{*zoom:1}.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{display:table;content:"";line-height:0}.clearfix:after{clear:both}.hide-text{font:0/0 a;color:transparent;text-shadow:none;background-color:transparent;border:0}
```

for example.

Comment: Use Notepad++. Edit --> Line Operations --> Remove empty Lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a text editor like Sublime text, you could use regex to get every space and then delete it.

Regex:

```
\s
```

If not, you can use simple website tools like:

[CSS Minifier](http://cssminifier.com/)

[Online YUI Compressor](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/)

[CSS Compressor](http://www.csscompressor.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try online `CSS` minifiers. Here is list for beginning:

- [CSSminifier.com](http://cssminifier.com/)
- [refresh-sf.com/yui/](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/)
- [CSScompressor.net](https://csscompressor.net/)
- [minifyCSS.com/css-compressor/](http://www.minifycss.com/css-compressor/)
- [And more..](https://www.google.com/search?q=minify+css+online)

Hopefully you will find useful for time being, and for future I'm recommending to start using `CSS` libraries such as `LESS` or `SASS`, which you can easily compress later on.